# WordPress loop to pull 4 pages/posts by ID

Tags: custom-post-types

Im trying to create a wordpress loop which pulls out 4 specific pages/posts by ID (excepts to display a teaser). The main issue is they are located in 3 different post types: 'post', 'training', 'page'.

So far I have rewrote this code 3 times, its nearly there but not quite right.

```
<?php
$ids = array(2101,3754,4760,2572);
query_posts(array(
'post_type' => array( 'post', 'training', 'page' ),
'post__in' => $ids,
'posts_per_page' => 1) 
);

if (have_posts()) : 
?>
```

Can anyone give me a pointer into what is going wrong?

Comment: I ***strongly*** recommend against using `query_posts`, you should use WP_Query or pre_get_posts instead

Answer (score 0):

Never under any circumstances use `query_posts`. There is no excuse.

Use WP_Query instead. [According to the WP_Query documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), `post_type` accepts a value of `'any'`.

```
$ids = array(2101,3754,4760,2572);
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'any',
    'post__in' => $ids,
    'posts_per_page' => 4
));

if ( $query->have_posts()) {
    while( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        the_title(); // etc
    }
    wp_reset_postdata(); // cleanup after our query
}
```

You also set it to return 1 post per page, but since you're not dealing with pagination, you want 4 posts, not 1, so increase that to 4

I would also advise against hardcoding your post IDs. A category name may be a better choice, or a 'featured items' taxonomy thats shared across both pages and posts, or better yet, a post meta value, with a metabox with a checkbox in it. All of which are subjects for other questions